# How I can capture the click of a button dynamically created? JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, click

I have two buttons on a form. Both the buttons and the form are created dynamically:

```
      container.html(........
                     ........
                     <input type='button' value='Send' id='btSend' />"+
                    "       <input type='button' value='Save' id='btSave' />"+
                     ................
                     ...............)
```

And here the two functions should collect keystrokes:

```
       $("#btSend").click(function(){
        ..........
        ............
        }

        $("#btSave").click(function(){
        ..........
        ............
        }
```

Comment: [event delegation with `.on`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: or register click events after posting that elements into the DOM

Comment: [Stack Overflow - Direct vs. Delegated - jQuery .on()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8111171/1641835)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.on()` to delegate `click` event to the dynamically created elements. see below code -

```
$(document).on("click","#btSend",function(){
        ..........
        ............
        }

 $(document).on("click","#btSave",function(){
        ..........
        ............
 }
```